# Why do I get this incorrect arithmetic calculation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I tried using the following code to calculate the average age of variables `John`, `Mary` and `Ahmed`, but it won't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a page for testing JavaScript</title>
    <script>
        var John = 23;
        var Mary = 25;
        var Ahmed = 22;
        var average = John + Mary + Ahmed / 3;
        console.log(average);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    JavaScript testing page, open the console and reload the page to see whats happening!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I played around and eventually found the correct way of doing it by adding an extra line with a sum variable:

```
var sum = John + Mary + Ahmed; var average = sum / 3
```

Was just wondering why my first attempt didn't work?

Comment: BODMAS? Did you not get any output or you got wrong output? I think it is Operator precedence issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of [operation precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). The value is actually this.

```
(John + Mary) + (Ahmed / 3);
```

You need to explicitly define the order like so.

```
(John + Mary + Ahmed) / 3;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, and I'm sorry this is so ridiculously late!

Comment: 2 years? That's nothing :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this

var average = (John + Mary + Ahmed) / 3;

what your code is doing is dividing Ahmed's age by 3 and then adding John and Mary's age to it.

putting brackets will calculate the sum first and then divide that sum by 3

Comment: Thanks mate! Much appreciated, I'm sorry this is such a late response

Answer (score 1):

Because what you're doing in this code is dividing ahmeds age by 3 to get 7.3, then adding that onto John and Mary's ages.

What you should do is var average = (John + Mary + Ahmed) / 3;